# Finding precedence of characters in a dictionary

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, topological-sort

**Given a dictionary of strings [ strings are in sorted order] you have to find the precedence of characters according to the dictionary..

> eat
>   bxy

e is ranked above b according to the dictionary!**

I tried to solve this question with topological sort and have written following code, it gave me an output of e-b-x-y-a-t. I could not be sure about my solution, any suggestions ? *(This question was asked in Google interview)*

```
  public static ArrayList<Vertex> topologicalSort (List<Vertex> graph){

    if (graph == null || graph.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    ArrayList<Vertex> result = new ArrayList<>(); 

    for (Vertex v : graph){
        if (!v.isVisited){
            dfs(v,result);
        }
    }
    return result;      
}

public static void dfs (Vertex v, ArrayList<Vertex> result){

    v.isVisited = true;

    for (Vertex adjVertex : v.AdjList){
        if (!adjVertex.isVisited){
            dfs(adjVertex, result);
        }
    }
    result.add(v);      
}

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Vertex> graph = new ArrayList<>();

        Vertex p1 = new Vertex("e");
        Vertex p2 = new Vertex("a");
        Vertex p3 = new Vertex("t");
        Vertex p4 = new Vertex("b");
        Vertex p5 = new Vertex("x");
        Vertex p6 = new Vertex("y");

        p1.AdjList = Arrays.asList(new Vertex[]{p2, p4});
        p2.AdjList = Arrays.asList(new Vertex[]{p3});
        p3.AdjList = Arrays.asList(new Vertex[]{});
        p4.AdjList = Arrays.asList(new Vertex[]{p5});
        p5.AdjList = Arrays.asList(new Vertex[]{p6});
        p6.AdjList = Arrays.asList(new Vertex[]{});

        graph.add(p1);
        graph.add(p2);
        graph.add(p3);
        graph.add(p4);
        graph.add(p5);
        graph.add(p6);

        ArrayList<Vertex> compileOrder = topologicalSort(graph);

        for( Vertex vertex : compileOrder){
        System.out.println(vertex.data );

        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what "precedence" means here. For example, how is a ranked in relation to e and b? Do you mean the order in which they first appear?

Comment: I think the order according to the dictionary.

Comment: e is ranked above a and, a is ranked above t, basically the order in which they appear.

Comment: With this dataset, all you can really say for certain is that e is ranked before b. You'll never know if your code is right until you create some better input data

Comment: From that sample, all you can tell is that `e` comes before `b`. That's it. You'll need more entries, such that either their first letters cover the entire alphabet, or that some of them have identical prefixes and the following letters cover the entire alphabet.

Comment: There is an additional trick in the question. The graph generation algorithm has to consider word with similar beginnings. So if you had  the words eat, ear then you need to add the pair t-r since it is implied since the ea part is common to both words.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you gave Top-Sort as answer, it would be right. In the given example, you have only 2 words. So, one thing you can be sure of is `e is before b` in the dictionary. You can't be sure of other characters. In the example, you have 6 characters.

Actually, every permutation of these 6 characters is a valid output, with the only constraint that `e` be placed before `b`. So, this example has !6/2 or 360 correct solutions.

For a larger dataset, your top-sort would work and I think that is a valid  solution.

Say, in example, you had 4 strings:

```
tak, eat, byx, bxy
```

Then, the only certain relations you have are:

```
t>e, e>b, y>x
```

All permutations of {t,a,k,e,b,x,y} having t before e, e before b and y before x will be a valid solution. And topsort will give one of those.